# Сбивается кодировка в MySQL

Tags: mysql, кодировка, utf-8, cp1251

Есть проблема: пытаюсь парсить название некоторых турниров с другого сайта. Название с русскими символами и прилетает нормально, вывожу через echo название - отображается корректно, например

```
Intel Extreme Masters XIII Chicago. Закрытые отборочные Северной Америки
```

Отправляю эту строку в свою таблицу в базе данных MySQL и на выходе получаю

```
Intel Extreme Masters XIII Chicago. Р—Р°РєСЂС‹С‚С‹Рµ РѕС‚Р±РѕСЂРѕС‡РЅС‹Рµ РЎРµРІРµСЂРЅРѕР№ РђРјРµСЂРёРєРё
```

Кодировка базы - `utf8_general_ci`, кодировка таблицы - `utf8_general_ci`, кодировка этого столбца также `utf8_general_ci`. Пытался менять кодировку столбца на `cp1251_general_ci` и это не помогло. Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3):

При создании подключения попробуй отправить запрос `SET NAMES 'utf8'`